# Unescaped text with th:alt

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In spring-boot / thymeleaf, some of the html views have a fiel like this :

```
 <img alt="STUB_name"
                th:alt="#{student.name}"
                 src="${url}/images/${locale}/mono.svg"
                 th:src="${@url} + '/images/' + ${lang} + '/mono.svg'" />
```

The value for student.name is placed on file message.properties.
The problem is the application don't resolve the unescaped text.

Anyone know how to use unescaped text with this tag th:alt?

Comment: Please read https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#configuring-a-conversion-service

Comment: Did not find related stuff there.

Comment: What is showing, and what do you want to show?

Comment: This is shown Fran&#231;ais. I actually want Français. I know it can be achieved with th:utext. But want to know how to achieve it with th:alt